# Python 'add' function issue: why won't this work?

Tags: python, function, addition

I've just started studying Python, and I'm an absolute newbie.

I'm starting to learn about functions, and I wrote this simple script:

```
def add(a,b):   
    return a + b

print "The first number you want to add?"
a = raw_input("First no: ")
print "What's the second number you want to add?"
b = raw_input("Second no: ")

result = add(a, b)

print "The result is: %r." % result
```

The script runs OK, but the result won't be a sum. I.e: if I enter 5 for 'a', and 6 for 'b', the result will not be '11', but 56. As in:

```
The first number you want to add?
First no: 5
What's the second number you want to add?
Second no: 6
The result is: '56'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all very much. So, as I understand it, a and b were returned as strings, rather than integers, therefore were being concatenated rather than added. Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, the `add` function has already been created! `from operator import add`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`raw_input` returns string, you need to convert it to int

```
def add(a,b):   
    return a + b

print "The first number you want to add?"
a = int(raw_input("First no: "))
print "What's the second number you want to add?"
b = int(raw_input("Second no: "))

result = add(a, b)

print "The result is: %r." % result
```

Output:

```
The first number you want to add?

First no: 5
What's the second number you want to add?

Second no: 6
The result is: 11.
```

Comment: No. Not "cast to int". It is not a casting, casting is something you do to tell a compiler that a variable contains a specific type of data. int() will *parse* a string and return* an integer. "parse" or "convert" are acceptable words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the strings to ints to add them, otherwise `+` will just perform string concatenation since `raw_input` returns *raw* input (a string):

```
result = add(int(a), int(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `raw_input()` returns a string and `+` operator has been overloaded for strings to perform string concatenation. Try.

```
def add(a,b):   
    return int(a) + int(b)

print "The first number you want to add?"
a = raw_input("First no: ")
print "What's the second number you want to add?"
b = raw_input("Second no: ")

result = add(a, b)

print "The result is: %r." % result
```

The resultant output is as follows.

```
>>> 
The first number you want to add?
First no: 5
What's the second number you want to add?
Second no: 6
The result is: 11
```

Converting the string inputs to `int`, uses the `+` operator to add the results instead of concatenating them.

.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `a` and `b` to integer.

```
def add(a, b):
    return int(a) + int(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

> **

**>**raw_input always returns string**. You need to **convert the strings to int/float datatype to add them**, otherwise addition will perform string concatenation.

*You can check the type of the variables yourself : `print(type(a), type(b))`*

**Simply tweak your function****

**

```
def add(a, b):
    return int(a) + int(b)
```

OR

```
def add(a, b):
    return float(a) + float(b)
```

Comment: Hi Soham, the main question of the asker is _why_ the function doesn't work. It would be more helpful to explain what is going wrong and why your code helps out.

Comment: Please consider adding a little bit of explanation too along with code .